# getting rid of not .DS_Store and .localized in OSx path from listdir

Tags: python, operating-system, tuples, listdir

I am making a tuple of all path but it also contains two extra paths

1. `/Users/sanjeevkumar/Pictures/.DS_Store`
2. `/Users/sanjeevkumar/Pictures/.localized`

how do i get rid of the above paths, 
I am generating the tuple path using the below technique

```
tuple(os.path.join(self._path,each) for each in os.listdir(self._path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self._path,each)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively I also realized that I can do it this way

```
tuple(os.path.join(self._path,each)
    for each in os.listdir(self._path) 
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self._path,each))
    and each.endswith('png') or each.endswith('jpg')
)
```

I think this will also help me get rid of any other file extension that could appear and is not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the `if` clause using `and` operator.

```
tuple(
    os.path.join(self._path,each)
    for each in os.listdir(self._path)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self._path,each))
    and each not in ('.DS_Store', '.localized') # <-------------
)
```